# Are questions with active bounties taken into consideration for selection of Hot Network Question section?

Tags: discussion, bounties, hot-questions

I referred to the following questions:  [*How do these arbitrary hotness points work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page) and [*What changed in the Hot Questions sidebar algorithm?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218247/what-changed-in-the-hot-questions-sidebar-algorithm) on MSE, but I am still curious to know whether questions that have an **active bounty** are also considered and counted to appear in Hot Network Question Section.

Can a bounty question which has received several upvotes and a healthy view count still enter the HNQ?

Comment: As far as I know, bounty does not affect in any way the hot questions algorithm.

Comment: This is already asked in a bigger scope.

Comment: HEY!! The original question linked has no answers!!!

Comment: So what? It was asked before, that is the meaning of duplicates.

Comment: Nop, it feels little weird: See this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261270/duplicates-of-unanswered-questions

Comment: @KaranDesai well the second point in the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261271/347191) applies..

Comment: @ShadowWizard This is not a duplicate. The older question is asking how effective is the bounty system for a question's visibility. Instead THIS question asks whether a bountied question can *also* enter the HNQ. The two are not the same and what's worse there are no answers in the older question. Now, if I wanted to post an almost similar question to this one, will that too be closed as a duplicate of a question with no answers?

Comment: If this question is reopened, I would like to place a small bounty on it.

Comment: I initially reviewed to leave this closed, but I read the second-to-last comment above and voted to reopen it.

Comment: @Sonic I don't have enough rep to see the reopen [history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history) page, I suspect it has been rejected by three users. Has it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, it has. But I've sought out reopen votes in chat. By the way, if you access the post timeline (`/posts/[post ID]/timeline`) you can see links to all completed reviews for a post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry, still think it's duplicate. If someone knows the answer for sure, they can add answer to the other question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the older question mentions HQN in passing, as an afterthought. The main focus of the older question is another, and questions without answers should not be used to close newer questions, which are phrased more clearly and simply.

Comment: You leave me with no choice but to write up a new question, which I will endeavor to make on-topic and not closeable as a duplicate. C'mon, don't make me do this. Let me add a bounty to this question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it's not "afterthought", it's part of bigger scope. Think of the "full rate limit guide" here on MSE for example. All kinds of rate limits belong there, so we don't go and post a different question for each type of rate limit. Right?

Comment: Woah what happened - marked as duplicate, then suddenly reopened - can anyone please explain =D I am confused

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this happens. Since August 4th this year, I've counted 18 instances of a question with an active bounty in the Hot Network Questions list:

- [How to gently enforce "nohello" to a coworker?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/119137), in HNQ from 2018-09-12 22:10:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-09-17 22:00:00 to 2018-09-18 13:50:00
- [Are Trolls immune to all instant death effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132519), in HNQ from 2018-09-27 13:10:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-09-30 01:20:00 to 2018-10-01 04:50:00
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/42268, in HNQ from 2018-09-13 14:20:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-09-16 12:40:00 to 2018-09-24 13:20:00
- [Is there any combination of two airports that are connected via taxiways?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/56305), in HNQ from 2018-10-23 01:30:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-10-27 22:10:00 to 2018-10-29 01:20:00
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/470440, in HNQ from 2018-09-21 08:10:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-09-23 05:50:00 to 2018-09-24 12:50:00
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194793, in HNQ from 2018-09-13 22:10:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-09-16 08:50:00 to 2018-09-17 05:40:00
- https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/18386, in HNQ from 2018-09-11 19:30:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-09-14 12:30:00 to 2018-09-17 14:10:00
- [Why did the Confederacy think they could win the American Civil War?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/48862), in HNQ from 2018-10-22 10:40:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-10-23 20:20:00 to 2018-10-29 10:10:00
- https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/34830, in HNQ from 2018-09-10 13:50:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-09-14 09:00:00 to 2018-09-15 15:40:00
- [I think my DM is consistently faking dice rolls for saves against a specific spell; how do I call my DM out?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134212), in HNQ from 2018-10-23 17:50:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-10-26 16:40:00 to 2018-10-29 15:40:00
- [What's the rationale for shipping coins back to Spain from its colonies?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/47723), in HNQ from 2018-08-22 13:00:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-08-24 21:30:00 to 2018-08-26 19:30:00
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/170229, in HNQ from 2018-08-08 15:50:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-08-11 01:00:00 to 2018-08-13 07:30:00
- [Why do airliners have to park so accurately?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54317), in HNQ from 2018-08-15 11:40:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-08-18 03:30:00 to 2018-08-20 10:20:00
- [What is Chirped Pulse Amplification, and why is it important enough to warrant a Nobel Prize?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/432137), in HNQ from 2018-10-02 18:50:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-10-04 21:10:00 to 2018-10-06 00:00:00
- [Why is the shape of a hanging chain not a "V"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/421957), in HNQ from 2018-08-09 20:20:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-08-12 18:00:00 to 2018-08-14 13:00:00
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/338849, in HNQ from 2018-10-07 18:00:00, in HNQ with bounty from 2018-10-10 04:00:00 to 2018-10-11 04:20:00

Two questions were already in the HNQ with an active bounty when I started scraping:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/q/190796, in HNQ with bounty from at least 2018-08-04 12:00:00 to 2018-08-04 21:30:00
- https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/119782, in HNQ with bounty from at least 2018-08-04 12:00:00 to 2018-08-07 17:30:00

The first 16 questions were already in the HNQ list just before the bounty was posted (I can't tell anything about the other two).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1278/discussion-on-answer-by-glorfindel-are-questions-with-active-bounties-taken-into).